# How do I correctly pass values down a widget tree in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a chart widget which has three required properties.

```
Min value
Max value
value
```

so I can create multiple chart widget's in a Listview like this:

```
class home extends StatefulWidget {
  const home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<home> createState() => _homeState();
}

class _homeState extends State<home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView(children: [gaugeChart(0, 100, cpuUsage), gaugeChart(0, 100, memoryUsage)]),
    );
  }
}
```

Inside the gaugeChart widget is a customPainter widget which needs the min, max and value at the end. If the value changes inside the setState it should update the widgets. So here's my question: How can I pass down these values to the customPainter function.

gaugeChart widget:

```
class gaugeChart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<gaugeChart> createState() => _gaugeChartState();
}

class _gaugeChartState extends State<gaugeChart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: gaugeChartPainter(),
    );
  }
}

class gaugeChartPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Inside here I need the min, max and value


  }
}
```

Comment: In `gaugeChartPainter` you could have a constructor that takes the min, max, and value parameters and stores those values in respective final member variable. Then access those variables from the `paint()` method. The constructor would get called when you call `setState` to update those variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) state management library.

First you need to define the provider in your main.dart. For example, wrap your MaterialApp in a MultiProvider widget and then define the ***providers*** property:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<MyClass?>(
      create: (_) => MyClass(),
    ),
```

1. Create a model class and a getter for each of your properties (make sure your class implements ChangeNotifier):

   ```
   class MyClass with ChangeNotifier {
   // property here
   }
   ```
2. Inside of your build method in your stateful widget, make the provider listen to the changes: `myClass= Provider.of<MyClass?>(context);`

You can then access any of the properties that you defined in **MyClass** above throughout the whole app, with just adding the line of code from step 2 above.